# appending a column on db result in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, eloquent

I am returning some results in my laravel app where I want to add a friendly time column to the returned results rather than showing the timestamp.

What I wanting to do is if the timestamp is today to show the time it was saved i.e. 09:45, if the created yesterday based on todays date, then I want to show "Yesterday" and if it is old than yesterday then I want to show a date "12/6/2020". I just cannot work out the logic using Carbon, here is my logic so far,

```
protected $appends = ['friendly_date'];

public function getFriendlyDateAttribute()
{
    if($this->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays("1") {
        return "Yesterday";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon offers a utility function to do this:

```
protected $appends = ['friendly_date'];

public function getFriendlyDateAttribute()
{
    if ($this->created_at->isToday()) {
        return $this->created_at->format('H:i');
    }
    if($this->created_at->isYesterday()) {
        return "Yesterday";
    }
    return $this->created_at->format('d/m/y'); // Assuming this is what 12/6/2020 means
}
```

Comment: According to my understanding, the OP would like to format today's timestamp too, eg.: `09:45`.

Comment: @marcell must have missed that part